# async await execution order - code only actually works when stepping through/debugging

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm hoping there is a simple answer here, and this is probably due to my misunderstanding of asynchronous operations...

I have a method that can be started manually or can autostart when the program loads. The async method works perfectly when invoked manually (on button press). However, when autoloaded the method just seems to skip the main "await" part of the method without performing any work, and skips straight to the end.

The whole process starts in this method:

```
private void StartBatch()
{
    var batchSize = (int)BatchSizeSlider.Value;

    if (_config.AutoStart)
    {
        ExecutionLogAddItem(string.Format("Auto batch processing started (batch size: {0})", batchSize.ToString()));

        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await BatchTransfer(batchSize);
            CompleteBatch();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var start = ConfirmStartBatch();
        var doBatch = start.ContinueWith(async (continuation) =>
        {
            //start task
            if (start.Result == true)
            {
                ExecutionLogAddItem("Batch processing started.");
                ExecutionLogAddItem(string.Format("Batch size set at {0}", batchSize.ToString()));
                await BatchTransfer(batchSize).ContinueWith((x) => CompleteBatch());
            }
            else
            {
                ExecutionLogAddItem("Batch processing aborted.");
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

If `_config.AutoStart` is true, the BatchTransfer method doesn't seem to do anything, instead the program skips straight to the `CompleteBatch()` method. If invoked manually everything works as expected.

The strange thing is, if I set a breakpoint on `await BatchTransfer(batchSize)` in the autostarted method, I can step through the code and the batch transfers take place. So when debugging it works, when not debugging it doesn't. Please help!

Comment: Is there a reason for using a ThreadPool thread inside `AutoStart`? i see that in your else clause you just await on the same thread.

Comment: I think we need more information. However, I am noticing 2 things: 1- in the else clause you're running ConfirmBatchStart but not in the if part. 2- You are not awaiting the Task started by the Factory method. (await Task.Factory.StartNew...)

Comment: @yuvalitzchakov: I wasn't sure how to use `await` inside a standard void. The manually started method includes `ConfirmStartBatch` which is a task that uses an aync message / confirmation box. I set a continuation from that to start the batch processing, but wasn't sure how to get the equivalent functionality without having first executed another async task.

Comment: @Dennis_E - The ConfirmBatchStart is another method that requires manual confirmation of batch start - should just return a bool that determines whether to execute the batch or not.  The factory method I am not sure how to await - I thought that's what `await BatchTransfer(batchSize)` did. Adding await (as in `await Task.Factory...` gives me an error that "the await operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier".

Comment: Why not to convert your `StartBatch` method as async and call normally with out creating `Task.Factory`.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar +1. If you control the code, make your StartBatch method to be truely `async`, then call it without `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: Yes, in order to await that Task, the StartBatch method itself has to be async. (That's what async does basically: it enables the await keyword)

Comment: As a general rule, it's best to avoid `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.ContinueWith`. Replace `ContineWith` with `await`; and (if you *really* need to execute code on a background thread) replace `StartNew` with `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because -

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await BatchTransfer(batchSize);
        CompleteBatch();
    });
```

You are waiting for the inner task to complete with `await` but `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>` itself is an asynchronous task and is not awaited. You should also wait for `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>` like this -

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

When you are debugging, the separate thread that is calling inner task is held and you can see the execution but when running normally the background is still working, but you cannot see it since you didn't wait for the `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>`.

If you check the thread pool and thread id, I am sure you will see that they are different when debugging.

This blog might help you understand the situation - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I've changed my method exactly like this. I added `async` to the method itself, then added `await Task.Factory.StartNew(async() => ...` but unfortunately it still isn't working as expected. The batch transfer just doesn't seem to execute at all.

Comment: There is another issue in my app, which means there is nothing to process in the autostarted method. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>` This only awaits the synchronous part of the lambda (before first `await`). Instead, you should use `await Task.Run(async () =>`: `Task.Run()` understands `async` lambdas, `Task.Factory.StartNew()` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `await` you have to make your method `async` and call it without `Task.Factory.StartNew`. One more thing, instead of `void` make return type as `Task` of your method because void async are fire and forget. You will not able to track them.

```
private async Task StartBatch()
{
    await BatchTransfer(batchSize);
    CompleteBatch();
}
```

Check this link. It have very basic demonstration of `async` and it is very helpful in understanding how `asynchrony` works. [Six Essential Tips For Async - Introduction](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Three-Essential-Tips-For-Async-Introduction). It includes six tips which are very essential. I recommend you go through all of them but to understand current question situation you can go through Tip 1 whose title is **Async void is for top-level event-handlers only**.